# Jquery datatable rendering slow for json string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

please help me, My Sql database has only 15000 rows in a table. but the loading time of jquery datatable is more than 6 sec. which is annoying for me.

I passed the jsonstring by ajax calling. Here is my javascript code and I am using web method.

```
  function testJson() {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService/Member/Client.asmx/TestJSON") %>',
             data: "{}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {

                 debugger;

                 var parsed = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                 $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                     "bProcessing": true,
                     "bDeferRender": true,
                     "bJQueryUI": true,
                     "bPaginate": true,
                     "bDestroy": true,
                     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                     "bFilter": true,
                     "bSort": false,
                     "sScrollY": 140,
                     "aaData": parsed,// <-- your array of objects
                     "aoColumns": [
                         { "mData": "_PIN" }, // <-- which values to use inside object
                         { "mData": "_AccountName" },
                         { "mData": "_FatherName" },
                         { "mData": "_MotherName" },
                         { "mData": "_BirthDateStr" },
                     { "mData": "_AccountName" },
                     { "mData": "_mphn" }
                     ]
                 });
             },
             error: function (msg) {

             }
         });
     };
```

Here is my Web method code:`

```
 [WebMethod]
      [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
      public string TestJSON()
      {
          DataTable dTable = BLClient.GetAllClientList();

          var lstAcc = new List<BOClient>();
          int i = 0;
          foreach (DataRow dr in dTable.Rows)
          {
              BOClient objClient = new BOClient();
              objClient._PIN = dr["PIN"].ToString();
              objClient._AccountName = dr["AccountName"].ToString();
              objClient._Branch_code = dr["Branch_code"].ToString();
              objClient._FatherName = dr["FatherName"].ToString();

              objClient._MotherName = dr["MotherName"].ToString();

              objClient._SpouseName = dr["SpouseName"].ToString();

              objClient._BirthDateStr = BLCommon.GetDateFormat_dd_mm_yyyy(dr["BirthDate"].ToString());

              objClient._mad1 = dr["mad1"].ToString();

              objClient._mphn = dr["mphn"].ToString();

              i++;

              lstAcc.Add(objClient);
          }
          System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
          jSearializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
          return jSearializer.Serialize(lstAcc);

      }
```

It Takes more than 6 sec Why and how can I get remedy from It.

Comment: 15000 rows is a lot of rows.

Comment: read docs on how to implement server side pagination using ajax

Comment: If you can't touch the server at the very least load in the data and use JS to do the pagination from the parsed JSON. Don't be loading 15000 rows into the page. That's just bad UX.

Answer (score 0):

If I last recall, you need to gather the offset so you don't return 15000 rows on each ajax request.  You should only return 10-100 rows in your SQL, which will boost your performance.

Datatables sends these variables to your ajax script:

```
 string RowStart = Request.Querystring["iDisplayStart"];  //ie: 10
 string ReturnLength = Request.Querystring["iDisplayLength"];  //ie: 25
```

Then offset your SQL data with those values that datatables uses for the ajax request.

For example, if `RowStart:10` and `ReturnLength:25` , then you should only return 25 rows starting from row 10.

I have a datatable working with hundreds of thousands of rows very quickly this way.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good method to render a big table like that on the front end, because it requires a large amount of memory to render the table, and potentially crashes the browser. You should return only a small number of rows at one time, and render it. When user scrolls down near the end of the table, use ajax to get more rows and render it.

6 seconds delay could be many things: the time sql processes the data + ajax + html rendering. Look into browser's developer toolbar to see where bottleneck is.